# How to define element in the XML, without creating unnessecery class

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I want that users will write xml as this one:

```
<Root>
    <Param>
        <Int>134</Int>
    </Param>
</Root>
```

or like this one:

```
<Root>
    <Param>
        <String>134</String>
    </Param>
</Root>
```

AND, I want that the auto-generated C# code of this xsd (I use xsd.exe) will not generate new class for Param, but will simply use `object`.

## First try

Now, when I write the xsd, I've started with this markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:element name="Int" type="xs:int"/>
                    <xs:element name="String" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

which yield this **good** code

```
public partial class Root {
    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

**BUT** the xml will look like:

```
<Root>
    <Int>134</Int>
</Root>
```

which is bad for my purposes.

## Second try

So, I've tried to fix the xsd, and that what I have now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Param">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice>
                            <xs:element name="Int" type="xs:int"/>
                            <xs:element name="String" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

NOW, the xml is like i want (with "Param" element), **BUT** now the code is ugly:

```
public partial class Root {
    public RootParam Param { get; set; }
}

public partial class RootParam {
    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

it creats unnessecery class (RootParam) that has in it only object. I would like to get code as beofre.

## So...

How can I do it? How to force element in the XML, **without** creating stupid fake unnessecery class?

Comment: How about Linq to Xml? `var xe = new XElement("Root",new XElement("Param", new XElement("Int","134"))); var xml = xe.ToString();`

Comment: Ok, but why you have the "stupid fake unnecessary" `param` element in the XML code in the first place?

Comment: @Marcel: client's request. In other situations, as sequence or sequence-in-sequence of xs:short, for instance, xsd.exe see `<Table><Row>1 2 3 4</Row><Row>1 2 3 4</Row><Row>1 2 3 4</Row></Table>` and generates `short[][] Table`, and doesn't create new class for Row nor Table. Just shorts.

Comment: @L.B: I need to read files to classes. Those class in thier turn are binded to WPF controls and have other things as well.